# How to use the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm working on my bachelor thesis and started collecting my books and articles using BibDesk 1.5.10. For the thesis itself, I use a template which includes `natbib` and references my bibliography like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\bibliography{Bibliographie}
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Every time I try to reference a paper from my library using `\cite{Low:2012aa}` all I get is a `?` at the corresponding place in my PDF.

Anyone here who has a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, then BibTeX, then LaTeX again (twice)?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/510

Comment: Oh dear, I forgot to bibtex my bibliography. Thanks for the heads up. Please write an answer. I'll accept it ASAP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)